# boost::bind along with qtconcurrent::map ...can't seem to make it work

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-bind, qtconcurrent

Well I require your assistance because I can't seem to find a way to make

[QtConcurrent::map](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtconcurrentmap.html#map) work with my 
static function and my sequence of elements.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

I want to run this function :

```
static void meta_engine_recursive(Node* node,OutputNode* output,Row *row);
```

On this set of elements:

```
QList<Row*> tasks;
```

Here is what I do for the call to map , but the compiler doesn't like it...I can't find the correct syntax even after reading all the boost & Qt documentation !

```
QFuture<void> future= QtConcurrent::map(tasks,
                            boost::bind(&VideoEngine::meta_engine_recursive,
                            boost::ref(dynamic_cast<Node*>(input)),
                            boost::ref(output),_1)(row));
```

Ps: obviously this is C++

Also , please don't mind the boost::ref calls, I was just playing around with it. What I want to resolve is the call to map with the good parameters

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: @lego "I don't like this code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind I didn't do the correct parenthesing and the extra (row) at the end wasn't necessary.
Here is the final call :

```
QFuture<void> future= QtConcurrent::map(tasks,
                                            boost::bind(&VideoEngine::meta_engine_recursive,
                                                        dynamic_cast<Node*>(input),
                                                        output,_1));
```